# What is treetop in this Cypher command?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match p = shortestpath ((n)-[*]-(treetop:Taxonomy))
```

I am seeing this in an tutorial but can't find the documentation on "treetop". Is it a function in Cypher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`treetop`, as used in your Cypher snippet, is the name of a variable. If that variable was  not already bound to a value (or values) earlier in the same Cypher statement, then it will be bound by your snippet. Once bound, a variable's value can be used by any later clauses in the same statement.